# Access denied accessing MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to access mysql database from PHP but why do I get error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sql.php on line 3
```

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I use the login PHP script, I use the correct password and everything

```
<?php


// login.php
$hn= 'localhost';
$db= 'publications';
$un= 'root';
$pw= 'password';
?>
```

And I get error in My PHP script, when I try to connect to it

```
<?php // query.php
     require_once 'login.php';
     $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db); // error here on line 3
     .
     .
     .
?>
```

Comment: Did you reload the permissions inside the mysql server after changing them? Apart from that we will only be able to help if you post your permission setup.

Comment: Side note: you should not use mysqls root account except for very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to make permissions in the sql server. Using `GRANT permissions on database.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` logged in as root. If this is silly sorry, because I'm new to PHP & SQL so I don't know yet exactly what was going on and where was the problem.

Comment: I was messed up all the permissions that I couldn't even set permissions logged in as root, So I just reinstalled  LAMPP ;D